# Алгоритм поиска телескопизмов

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть список слов

```
bulb
queen
dinosaur
```

Есть строка `Bulbasaur`. Как мы видим это составная часть двух слов выше - **bulb** и din**osaur**.

```
lines = []
fh = open('input.txt')
for line in fh:
    lines.append(line.strip())
fh.close()

str = 'Bulbasaur'

newlist = []

for line in lines:
    if line in str.lower():
        newlist.append(line)
        str = str.replace(line,"")

for line in lines:
    if str.lower() in line:
        newlist.append(line)
        str = str.replace(line,"")
```

Данный код в принципе корректно находит эти телескопизмы, но чувствую я тут накидал индусского кода. Подскажите более красивый вариант

Comment: Где точное определение "телескопизма"? Почему слово "bulbasaur" является телескопизмом для слов "bulb" и "dinosaur"? Откуда взялась "a"

Comment: @AnT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau

Comment: @AnT https://studopedia.su/13_142884_teleskopiya.html

Comment: @Radzhab стоит посмотреть, как с этой задачей справились другие - https://github.com/darius/languagetoys/blob/master/portmanteau.py

Comment: @nikialeksey там тупо генерация слов

Comment: интересно, ваш алгоритм сможет найти `Bulbasaur` со входом `ulbasaur, dinosaur, bulb` ?